# How to find a sort/query in a collection with the most recent time

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection called sceanarios with documents, that have different two gmt times `createDate` and `updateDate`. I would like to query/sort documents, based on what has the most recent time regardless of whether the more recent time is in createDate or updateDate.

Comment: I guess if there's an updateDate it's always more recent than the createDate? Then why don't you just add an updateDate = createDate to all the documents that haven't been updated and always use that? I think that would be a lot less hassle than finding the minimum of both in find and sort.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with aggregation framework, like this:

```
db.yourColl.aggregate(
                 {$project:{ 
                     greaterDate:
                                {$cond:[{$gt:["$createDate","$updateDate"]},
                                 "$createDate",
                                 "$updateDate"]
                                }
                           }
                 },
                 {$sort:{ greaterDate:-1}})
```

However you need to enumerate all fields you want to keep in $project section